# Android actionbar NavMode.Tabs how to change highlight color?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm not using Tabhost (and I don't want to) and I've tried everything:

this is my actionbar and I'm using holo light with dark action bar

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I tried using this useful website without success.

I also tried unsuccessfully with

```
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new      ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_brown_dark)));
```

here is my styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Lemonbar</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>
```

Lemonbar is the style which overrides Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar and it's created using android action bar style generator.
When I launch the app the actionbar is still the same as before like the new style is not applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [google guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs) for this.

Comment: I did, I only get a white actionbar. I need to have a dark one, what's the xml code of the dark actionbar?  I mean Holo.light.DarkActionBar or something

Comment: @codareee well it is pretty the same you wrote https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes just use the one you want

Comment: thanks. I don't know why but I was getting an error writing it. still trying to fix the problem in the question though.

Comment: @codareee so wath's the problem with tab styling? does not the XML code in guide provide an answer?

Comment: @codareee do you have only one `styles.xml`? Because usually there are 3 or 4 of them automaticly generated by Eclipse for different Android versions. So if you are testing on device with v.4 and edit `style.xml` not in `values-v14` folder, but in plain `values` you can't see the effect as the values are overriden by higher config file.

Comment: yeah I have multiple styles.xml, I've just noticed :facepalm: Anyway if I set the actionbar style in "AppTheme" it should apply on any version right? if I do so the actionbar doesn't show at all. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @codareee maybe the style you are using in not implemented under Android version on device you are testing at. Usually you better use different `style` files as it protects you from such cases. And you are right - theme defined in the manifest is applieyd with no dependence from Android version.

Comment: i'm testing/targeting android 4.2.2 supporting from android 4.0.
I solved setting the generated theme as the app theme btw

Answer (score 0):

It is called the Tab Indicator . You many find this [android's develop guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs) to be useful.